# jquery datatable row position (height)

Tags: jquery, datatable

I use the datatable from jquery to show and edit some data on my website. But I have a little problem when editing the value's in the columns. 
When I press the edit button in the row, my datatable jums a little, because of this, I have to scroll again to view the editing row. Also when I press save, the datatable jumps again. 
first after saving or pressing the edit button my tablescroll went back to the top. But I could solve this already by placing oTable.fndraw() in comment. But it it still isn't working like it should. 
So what I want is: That when you press the edit button, that the table doesn't change from position, so your row is still on the same place, and when you press the save button it also stays on the same place.

First I thought it could be because I used paging, but when I disabled the paging I got the same problem. 
Does someone maybe knows where I could solve this problem?

Comment: I tried it, but that moment I had to wait 8 hours before I could place it as an answer. But thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to the second problem: the height of the rows. Wish also gave me the answer to my first question: how could I stay at the same place when editing a table row. Well, it was like I thought: the row height. So I tried to change the height of the rows and it worked.

it's not in the css files that you have to change the height of the rows, but in a style tag. like this:

```
<style type="text/css" title="currentStyle">
    @import "../javascript/3rdParty/jquery/css/table.css";
    tr { height: 50px; }
</style>
```

The rows have all now the same height and I don't have the problem anymore with the scrolling of the table.

extra note: 
If you have more tables in your page, don't forget to add the id before the tr. Else all the table rows will have the given height.